# Update the data into SQL lite database from one device to other via Bluetooth in android

Tags: php, android, html, asp.net, xml

I have two apps client and server app.I store data of both app into sql lite database.
I need to send the data from server app and that should be stored in client app database via Bluetooth.Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes sure,
you need first to decide on the Bluetooth protocol you need to use, if you have a lot of data to send I suggest to use Bluetooth RFCOMM.
Here is a [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html) on how to use Bluetooth RFCOMM. Once your data is recieved in the client application, you add it in the sqlite database tables

Comment: Thank you for answerd to my question. I connected both app via Bluetooth its work like chat app but How can i store that chat messages into local database..